# find string in svn repository

Tags: windows, batch-file, grep, findstr

I have the URL of a svn repository located at a remote location. I want to search recursively for the presence of a string in one of the folders  using `findstr` command. Is it possible or findstr is only to be used to search local folders ?

Comment: Presence of a string in a particular folder and its subfolders and files located at a remote SVN

Comment: How about `findstr /?`? See parameter `/s`

Comment: If you expect batch to open an URL - no chance. You have to use a tool for that. Tool can be called from batch.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. Just use the recursive flag `-R` of `svn ls`. Then pipe the output to `findstr`.

Assuming you are looking for a directory named 'needle':

```
svn ls -R URL-OF-REPO | findstr needle
```

Comment: and to find files with a specific extension you do `svn ls -R URL-OF-REPO | findstr needle | find ".txt"`